# Jekyll/Liquid complex expressions

Tags: jekyll, liquid

How do do formulate in Jekyll/Liquid language the following expression:

if (A and B) or (not C)

What are the rules globally (precedence, left,right) ?

Comment: https://shopify.github.io/liquid/basics/operators/#order-of-operations

Comment: not C , b or not C, a and ... that doesn't respect the parenthesis !

Answer (score 0):

Parentheses won't work, all precedence rules are detailed here:
https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/tags/control-flow-tags#multiple-conditions-and-or

Comment: Ok but in my case, I don't see how to formulate/translate in Jekyll/liquid language, by hand, my expression

Comment: Liquid is used by Jekyll and Shopify and works the same for both.